# Rename files uniquely during uploading

Tags: php, file, file-rename

I want to upload images and have them renamed after the user's full name. That worked well but i want them named uniquely by adding a number so for example. `Fname_Lname_1.jpg` , `Fname_Lname_2.jpg` ,etc. My problem is that,the number increment doesn't occur. What rather happens is the first file being replaced by the newly uploaded one cos the newly uploaded file assumes the name of the first file.

```
<?php 
require 'Connections/Conn.php';
require 'core/init.php';

if(isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
}else{
    header('Location: Login.php');
}

//Parse UserId into variable $userid
$userid =  $_SESSION["UserID"];
//Parse User Fname, '_' & Lname into variable userfullname
$userfullname = $_SESSION["LName"].'_'.$_SESSION["FName"];
//Add UserID and userfullname and parse it into foldername
$foldername = $userid.'_'.$userfullname;

//Now save the path into this variable
$enclosedFolder="./Users/" . $foldername . "/Main/";

// Count sent by plugin
$Images =count(isset($_FILES['images']['name'])?$_FILES['images']['name']:0);
$infoImagesUploaded = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $Images; $i++) {


    // The name and the temporary file name we're gonna attach
    $fileName=isset($_FILES['images']['name'][$i])?$_FILES['images']['name'][$i]:null;
    $fileTemp=isset($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i])?$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i]:null;

    $numb = 0;  
    $newfilename = $userfullname.'_'.($numb++).".jpg";


    $pathFile=$enclosedFolder.$newfilename;

    move_uploaded_file($fileTemp,$pathFile);
    $infoImagesUploaded[$i]=array("caption"=>"$fileName","height"=>"120px","url"=>"MainDelete.php","key"=>$fileName);
    $ImagesUploaded[$i]="<img  height='120px'  src='$pathFile' class='file-preview-image'>";


}

$arr = array("file_id"=>0,"overwriteInitial"=>true,"initialPreviewConfig"=>$infoImagesUploaded, "initialPreview"=>$ImagesUploaded);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: The general way of doing this is creating a unique id (*via [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid) most of the time*) and also attaching a timestamp to it. Example: `uniqid() . '_' . $userfullname . '_' . time() . ".jpg";`. It's also not the best to force a `.jpg` extension, might want to create that as per the uploaded image.